# What is the difference between EnumerateFiles and EnumerateFileSystemEntries in .NET 4?

Tags: c#, .net

In .Net 4 there are two functions to enumerate files in a path. The EnumerateFiles and EnumerateFileSystemEntries. The MSDN does not give enough explanations about their differences. Which are these differences?

Answer (score 29):

[EnumerateFileSystemEntries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.enumeratefilesystementries.aspx) => enumerate files, directories, and **both files and directories**.

[EnumerateFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles.aspx) => for enumarting **only files**. (Not directories)

Answer (score 8):

[`EnumerateFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles.aspx) returns only file names. [`EnumerateFileSystemEntries`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413381.aspx) returns *names of directories* also

Answer (score 1):

As @Habib and @Sergey answered, you need to use `EnumerateFileSystemEntries` instead of `EnumerateFiles`. I will extend their answers with an example.

- [EnumerateFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles.aspx): Returns an enumerable collection of file names that match a search pattern in a specified path, and optionally searches subdirectories.
- [EnumerateFileSystemEntries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413381.aspx): returns an enumerable collection of file names and directory names in a specified path.

Here is a code to showcase the difference:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory("dir");
    Directory.CreateDirectory("dir2");
    File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine("dir", Path.GetRandomFileName()), "file");
    var datapath = ".";

    var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(datapath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    files.Dump();

    var fileSystemEntries  = Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(datapath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    fileSystemEntries.Dump();
}
```

output

```
Dumping object(System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1[String])
[
   .\dir\epp3114y.jjr
]
Dumping object(System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1[String])
[
   .\dir
   ,
   .\dir2
   ,
   .\dir\epp3114y.jjr
]
```

[Try it Online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gwsYSC)

Comment: The syteme works! Closing a question as dupe, and answering on the dupe and not answering every dupe. Here is a vote! Et en bonus si tu passes en bretagne je t'offre une crêpe!

Comment: @xdtTransform ha ha thank you. Ok pour la crêpe! Tu es dans quel coin?