# Get all Files and Folders in a Folder

Tags: c#

Currently i use this to get all files in a folder:

```
IEnumerable<string> files;
files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(datapath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

where `datapath` is just a `string` with the folder path.

With this i get all files and also the folders that contain files, but if i have empty folders i don't get them.

I thought about using `Directory.EnumerateDirectories` but than i would have all directories, even those that where already found by `Directory.EnumerateFiles`

Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: You can try something like this: Loop through your IEnumerable and do:  `var folder = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    if (folder.Exists)
    {
        return folder.GetFileSystemInfos().Length == 0;
    }`

Comment: `EnumerateFiles` enumerates *files*, not dictionaries. The method that enumerates both is `EnumerateFileSystemEntries`

Comment: @Joel `GetFileSystemInfos()` will return only after all results are found. It's better to use the `Enumerate...` methods. In any case that snippet doesn't do what the OP asked, it only checks whether the root folder is empty or not, in a rather expensive way. `EnumerateFileSystemInfos().Any()` would do the same but return immediatelly

Comment: @AlpakaJoe This is a good question. You are not the only one to face this issue. Please close your question and see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55397513/1248177).

Answer (score 0):

You should use Directory.GetDirectories and then for each folder and file you can ran foreach loop. You can read more about this solution here http://www.csharp411.com/c-copy-folder-recursively/

Comment: This is too complicated when you have a simpler handy solution. Check the duplicate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55397513/1248177).